# HTML5 FileReader API - how to remove a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filereader

I am using the HTML 5 FileReader API to preview images before upload to a server.

As `FileReader` doesn't have a `remove()` method, how I can remove an item from the list?

**Here is my code**

```js
        $("body").on('change', '.files', function() {

          //Get count of selected files
          var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;

          var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
          var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
          var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
          image_holder.empty();

          if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
            if (typeof(FileReader) != "undefined") {

              //loop for each file selected for uploaded.
              for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) {

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                  $("<img />", {
                    "src": e.target.result,
                    "class": "img-thumbnail img-responsive",
                    "width": "100",
                  }).appendTo(image_holder);
                }

                image_holder.show();
                reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
              }

            } else {
              alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
            }
          } else {
            alert("Pls select only images");
          }
        });
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="image-holder"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Files` object is a **readonly** array-like object,
so modifying it is a no-go.
One technique seems to be immediately copying its elements into an actual Array
and then manipulating the array as needed.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an alternative to using FileReader:

```
// var placed here so that other functions can manipulate
var filesChangeable = []; 
function fileInfo(event){
                       event.preventDefault();

                   // files contains the array of dropped images
                       var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
                       previewFiles(files);

                       function previewFiles(files) {

                       for (var k=0; k<files.length; k++) {

                       var file = files[k];
                       filesChangeable.push(files[k]);    

                       $("#demo").append("<img src='"+URL.createObjectURL(filesChangeable[k])+"' />");

                   }
```